# ASP.NET Core DbContext injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `ConfigurationDbContext` that I am trying to use.  It has multiple parameters, `DbContextOptions` and `ConfigurationStoreOptions`.

How can I add this DbContext to my services in ASP.NET Core?

I have attempted the following in my Startup.cs:

```
ConfigureServices
....
services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(BuildDbContext(connString));
....


private ConfigurationDbContext BuildDbContext(string connString)
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer(connString);

    var options = builder.Options;

    return new ConfigurationDbContext(options, new ConfigurationStoreOptions());
}
```

Comment: do you use mssql server

Comment: yes.  But, to construct the dbcontext, I require to pass another parameter to it.

Comment: i  have also added example link

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`AddDbContext` [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L475) just registers the context itself and its common dependencies in DI. 
Instead of `AddDbContext` call, it's perfectly legal to manually register your DbContext:

```
services.AddTransient<FooContext>();
```

Moreover, you could use a factory method to pass parameters (this is answering the question):

```
services.AddTransient<FooContext>(provider =>
{
    //resolve another classes from DI
    var anyOtherClass = provider.GetService<AnyOtherClass>();

    //pass any parameters
    return new FooContext(foo, bar);
});
```

P.S., In general, you don't have to register `DbContextOptionsFactory` and default `DbContextOptions` to resolve DbContext itself, but it could be necessary in specific cases.

Comment: Broken link - this is the file https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: It looks like AddDbContextPool also does the same

Comment: @Simon_Weaver thanks, I've updated the link. `DbContextPool` is something added in Core 2.0 I guess.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this in startup.cs.

Detail information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Detail Example : [Getting started with ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>options.
       UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to register `DbContext` as a service in `IServiceCollection` you have two options:(we assume that you are going to connect to a SQL Server database)

**Using AddDbContext<>**

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(o=>o.UseSqlServer(Your Connection String));
```

**Using AddDbContextPool<>**

```
services.AddDbContextPool<YourDbContext>(o=>o.UseSqlServer(Your Connection String));
```

as you might see these two are in terms of writing have similarities, but in fact they have some fundamental differences in terms of concepts. @GabrielLuci has a nice response about the differences between these two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444206/1666800

Also note that you can store your connection string inside the appsettings.json file and simply read it using: `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` inside the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: I have a question. If I add dbcontext in StartUp.cs, do I have to use `AddSingleton` or 'AddScoped` or `AddTransient` etc?

Comment: @Hello starting with .NET core 2.0 by using AddDbContextPool you do not need to use AddTransient or AddSingleton or AddScoped methods. Read these for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484724/1666800 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443567/adddbcontext-or-adddbcontextpool

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply, I don't use AddDbContextPool. I just use AddDbContext. Because I followed an example at [here](https://hackernoon.com/asp-net-core-how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-entity-framework-core-4388fc5c148b), it doesn't use this kind of things, I don't understand it.

Comment: @Hello nice. you can read more about these two function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.1 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextpool?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you, I got it. The default is `AddScoped`

Answer (score 1):

Try this for inject your ef context - context inheritance from IDbContext

1-Add your context to service:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<NopaDbContext>(
                        options => options
                        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NopaDbContext")),ServiceLifetime.Scoped);}
```

2-Inject your context:

```
    private readonly IDbContext _context;

    public EfRepository(NopaDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                _entities = _context.Set<TEntity>();

            return _entities;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your parameters of db context in a class `AppDbContextParams` and register a factory to create that object for appdbcontext:

```
services.AddScoped(sp =>
            {
                var currentUser = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
                return new AppDbContextParams { GetCurrentUsernameCallback = () => currentUser ?? "n/a" };
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

EF Core 6 / .NET 6 has some changes to make it easier (and supported) to register DbContext and DbContextPool at the same time for different usages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#dbcontext-factory-improvements