# Transient IDisposable Memory Leak

Tags: c#, .net, memory, dependency-injection, memory-leaks

I have troubleshooted a memory leak within my application down to an improper use of a transient Idisposable service.

The service is implemented as

```cs
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{

}
```

It is injected as

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddUnitOfWork(this IServiceCollection services)
    => services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork>(services => new UnitOfWork(services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>()));
```

and it is usually consumed like this

```cs
void DoStuff()
{
    using var uow = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
}
```

The thing is, there are way too many consumers that get the service that way, making it almost impossible to refactor the whole codebase.

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#idisposable-guidance-for-transient-and-shared-instances) guidance states that a factory pattern should be used instead. Is there any way where I can change the injection part of the code and avoid the memory leak without changing every consumers?

I have tried using multiple ways of injecting the service, they all seem to cause a memory leak.

Comment: Is `serviceProvider` a root scope of the application?

Comment: Sadly yes and I don't think there's a way around that with the current architecture

Comment: Maybe you can change the implementor of IUnitOfWork  that it creates/destroys the dependency that it needs to be disposed on a per method call basis? That would make IDisposable needless and gets rid of the problem without a mayor change and just moves the disposable stuff into the methods of the IUnitOfWork implementor.

Comment: Have you tried just registering it as `.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork>()`

Comment: Yes, In any case the service provider keeps track of those instances even if they are disposed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem here is that you are working with the same scope (highly likely the root one) which will not release the objects (note that scope on the disposal will dispose the services which implement `IDisposable`). You need to rework your app so the UoW holding scope is disposed:

```
void DoStuff()
{
    using var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var uow = serviceScope.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>(); // no need for using
} // uow will be disposed here with the holding scope
```

Sometime ago I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602061/2501279) approach to capture such scenarios.

Comment: This is clear to me, however the point of my question is to find a solution that does not affect the consumer code and only affects the injection part of the code

Comment: @NiccolòPecora AFAIK there is none without any code modifications on the caller side. Possibly something can be done by switching to another DI container which will not store the objects. Or some ugly reflection.