# Is there any reason to still use AddDbContext in .NET Core 3.0 and above?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-3.0

When building new app in .NET Core 3 (or above), is there any reason to still use `AddDbContext`, instead of `AddDbContextPool`? If so, shouldn't `AddDbContext` be marked obsolete at this point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddDbContext or AddDbContextPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443567/adddbcontext-or-adddbcontextpool). That references ASP.NET Core 2, but your question gives no reason why 3 should be different -- note that the accepted answer implies the semantics are sufficiently different that the uses are not interchangeable and hence there's still a case for both.

Comment: Thanks. As I'm reading this, it looks like the only reason to still use `AddDbContext` is when you use private variables inside DbContext that you don't want to share. Otherwise you should always use DbContextPool (better performance). I'm not 100% sure, if I missed something though

Comment: @IshThomas That should be enough for not making `AddDbContext` "obsolete". And having private fields or constructor injected state is de facto standard for single database multi-tenant db contexts.

Comment: Use AddDbContext. Pooling DbContext instances is probably the wrong way to solve your performance issues. Try caching HTTP responses first.

Comment: @bricelam I have an endpoint where I need to perform 5 parallel DbContext queries. So in old fashion way I have `AddDbContext` and simple factory, where I "new-up" new DbContexts.I thought Pooling is the way to go nowadays, no?

Comment: A factory is perfect for this scenario. We (the EF team) are considering adding one by default when you call AddDbContext for those times when you need a new instance inside of a request scope. Pooling might help with perf in very specific scenarios, but it's unrelated to service scopes